# “Leakage” in context

Tags: meaning, nouns, translation

I have been reading a text about spotting lies by analysis of voice, gestures, etc., and cannot understand the word *leakage* in this sentence:

> ... clues of emotions... These are what provide leakage or deception clues.

Is it related to clues (leakage clues or deception clues), or does it mean leakage on the liar’s side (unintentionally revealing he is lying)?

All dictionaries mention only two meanings of *leakage*: physical (such as of liquid) or deliberate disclosure of information. Neither fits here for me.

Comment: I cannot verify your claim that dictionaries record it only for the deliberate disclosure of information. [thefreedictionary.org](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/leaking) quotes The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language, Fourth Edition as follows: "[...] _Informal_ `An unauthorized` **or** `a deliberate` disclosure of confidential information[...]" (emphasis mine)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mention two senses of *[leakage](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/leakage)*; but the sense appropriate here is analogous to sense 3 at above link:

> an undesirable flow of electric current through insulation

Your text is suggesting that the liar's body language involuntarily leaks information to the careful observer.

Note, “provide leakage or deception clues” is not saying “provide leakage clues or deception clues”, but instead “provide leakage; or, clues to deception”.